# Closing Bootstrap Modal doesn't stop JW Player

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, jwplayer

I have JW PLayer embedded in a Bootstrap modal (not iframe/youtube). It plays fine but when closing the modal (either by clicking the "x" or clicking outside the dialog) the audio continues to play. I was able to stop it by adding :
    onclick='jwplayer().stop()'
to the close button.

However this doesn't help when the modal is closed by clicking outside the dialog (modal-backdrop). Can anybody help? I'm a bit of a js noob!

Here is the url: http://bit.ly/1g4Dz3o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the click that you have attached.

If you check their [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage), you will find event `hide.bs.modal` which is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.

```
$('#videohome').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
  jwplayer().stop();
})
```